# Choosing between gRPC with endpoints, or REST in a simple app to work like a BackEnd app deployed in GAE

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

I'm developing an app deployed in GAE, simple for this moment. This app is the backend of other app. 
Internally, this app have a few modules (this is not important here) that they communicate with rest apis (for other reason).

And the question that I'm thinking is: I was beginning to write API (to outside) using gRPC and EndPoints like GAE docs says, when I thought that if I could have really advantages if using gRPC and not REST like internally.
I have been spend a lot of time searching that really advantages that offers gRPC about REST, but I don't find it.

Why Google recommended gRPC? Is faster than REST?, (from my point of view is most simple to write)
You know any test about speed with both technologies?
I will thanking any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GRPC today on AppEngine's [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) platform as both a client and a server. If you want load balancing you need to use [TCP/IP load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/) and have GRPC servers terminate TLS for you.

GRPC does not yet work on AppEngine standard but we're working on it. For more questions hit up the mailing list.